# Debugging and Visualization of a parallel program

Tags: python, debugging, parallel-processing

This is a code for debugging and visulization. When I run the code the graph sits at 0.00 and I am not sure if it is working properly. Can someone help me get this code right and make sure it is a good representation of debugging and visulization.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def worker_function(index, results, lock):
    # Simulate some work
    time.sleep(random.random() * 2)
    result = index * index

    # Store the result in the shared results
    with lock:
        results[index] = result

def run_parallel_program(num_workers, progress_var):
    # Create a shared array to store the results
    results = multiprocessing.Array('i', num_workers)

    # Create a lock to protect the shared results array
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    # Create and start a pool of workers
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for i in range(num_workers):
        pool.apply_async(worker_function, (i, results, lock))

    # Close the pool and wait for all tasks to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Update progress variable
    progress_var.set(100)

    # Return the results as a list
    return list(results)

def plot_execution_times(results):
    plt.plot(results)
    plt.xlabel("Worker")
    plt.ylabel("Execution Time (seconds)")
    plt.title("Execution Times of Parallel Workers")
    plt.show()

def start_processing():
    num_workers = int(entry.get())
    progress_var.set(0)  # Reset progress bar

    # Run parallel program
    results = run_parallel_program(num_workers, progress_var)

    # Update progress bar to 100% after completion
    progress_var.set(100)

    # Plot execution times
    plot_execution_times(results)

# Create Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Parallel Processing Demo")

# UI components
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Number of Workers:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

entry = ttk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Processing", command=start_processing)
start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, length=200, mode="determinate")
progress_bar.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Run the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code above like i stated i want to know why when ran the graph stays at 0.00 and if its a good way of showing debugging and visulization of a parallel program. Please Help and as quickly as possible if you have the time I would really appreciate it!!

My overall question is: Is this code correct for debugging and visualization if so can someone explain to me why when I run it the graph sits at 0.0.

Comment: Hi Smor, can you make your question more clear or outline what the question / problem is. This makes it easier to help you :)